# Doxygen - make all occurrences of a word reference the same thing

Tags: documentation, doxygen

This in reference to a normal page documentation.

I was wondering if it was possible to make each occurrence of a word reference something (in this case linking to a class documentation.

example

```
/**
@mainpage Blah
@re com.blah.class label = Class **(or something)**

If you notice Class does this.
...
...

This is because the way Class works...
...
@endmainpage
*/
```

and in the page, as you read, you can click into the word Class to take you to the documentation

Comment: To be more clear, instead of having to do this everywhere
@ref com.blah.class "Class"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page is put in the right context (namespace/package) then it should work, e.g. see the following (C++) example:

```
/** A namespace */
namespace N
{
  /** A class */
  class C
  {
  };

  /** @mainpage My main page
   *  Class C is linked here!
   */
}

/** @page mypage A Page 
 *  Class C is not linked, but N::C is.
 */
```

An alternative would be to use

```
/** @page mypage A Page 
 *  Class @l{C} is not linked, but N::C is.
 */
```

Along with the following alias definition in the config file:

```
ALIASES                = l{1}="@ref N::\1 \"\1\""
```